# How to display task without due date before the task with due date

Tags: taskwarrior

I want to display the task in descending order of due date (as I have a long list of tasks and want to have the ones with lowest due date at first and not having to scroll up to see them) and therefore display the task without due date before the task with due date.

Here is the content of my `.taskrc` file

```
data.location=~/.tasktest

report.simple.columns=id,project,due,urgency
report.simple.sort=due-
report.simple.filter=status:pending
```

Here is the content of the file `pending.data`:

```
[description:"description1_2: blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla" due:"1625954400" entry:"1625487626" modified:"1625823811" project:"project1.subproject1_2" status:"pending" tags:"tag1,tag2" uuid:"e28d104a-4fca-46a9-8468-200407fa02e7"]
[description:"description1_1 blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla" due:"1625695200" entry:"1625492019" modified:"1625823829" project:"project1.subproject1_1" status:"pending" tags:"tag1" uuid:"f1458cc3-0fb8-467f-a7b4-743fa72f8706"]
[description:"description3_1: blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla" due:"1627164000" entry:"1625501018" modified:"1625823844" project:"project3.subproject3_1" status:"pending" uuid:"b3d974ec-4871-4258-a1a7-ac5ebee42840"]
[description:"blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla" due:"1626732000" entry:"1625520776" modified:"1625583092" project:"project2.subproject2_1.subproject2_1_2" status:"pending" uuid:"f9e18d14-d628-40bc-a58b-43bdbe3cf815"]
[description:"blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla" entry:"1625520879" modified:"1625824409" project:"project2.subproject2_1.subproject2_1_3" status:"pending" uuid:"2caf1eec-b33f-4cf7-8d55-5c5b0f1c835c"]
[description:"description_5" entry:"1625824928" modified:"1625824928" project:"project5" status:"pending" uuid:"c943be0b-3491-4d0e-a092-aba9666044bf"]
```

Here is the current output of `task simple`(output n°1):

```
ID Project                                Due        Urgency
-- -------------------------------------- ---------- -------
 3 project3.subproject3_1                 2021-07-25    3.42
 4 project2.subproject2_1.subproject2_1_2 2021-07-20    5.02
 1 project1.subproject1_2                 2021-07-11      10
 2 project1.subproject1_1                 2021-07-08    11.3
 5 project2.subproject2_1.subproject2_1_3               1.02
 6 project5                                                1

6 tasks
```

want I want is to display the tasks 5 and 6 before the tasks 3,4,1,2 as follows (output n°2):

```
ID Project                                Due        Urgency
-- -------------------------------------- ---------- -------
 5 project2.subproject2_1.subproject2_1_3               1.02
 6 project5                                                1
 3 project3.subproject3_1                 2021-07-25    3.42
 4 project2.subproject2_1.subproject2_1_2 2021-07-20    5.02
 1 project1.subproject1_2                 2021-07-11      10
 2 project1.subproject1_1                 2021-07-08    11.3

6 tasks
```

How could I obtain the output n°2?

Answer (score 1):

What you want can be done by leveraging [`urgency`](https://taskwarrior.org/docs/urgency.html). I believe that this truly matches your intent, even though the question is strictly asking for sorting by `due date`.

As you can already see in your desired output example, it's already sorted by `urgency`. You can change report sorting to:

```
report.simple.sort=urgency-
```

Urgency uses coefficients for each property, the default for `urgency.due.coefficient` is `12.0`. Play with this value for your workflow, as urgency is influenced by other properties such as `priority` or `depends`: increasing the weighting will make tasks that are due soon have higher score.